# Clean iPhone - clean up

Tags: iphone, macos

1. I have iPhone with `ios6` is it possible to clean all the data under
   /Application without jailbreaking it?
2. How can I clean and make more free room on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by /Applications in the context you're using it. Each app has its own directory structure and the developer decides how to best organize that data. For example, some use libraries and others, documents.

That said, what you can do to release space, are the following:

1. Delete the app from the device. That will delete its data. Then restore the app from iTunes, or the cloud.
2. Use something like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) or [Phone Disk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/?utm_source=iExplorer%20%28Mac%29&utm_medium=desktop%20app&utm_campaign=iExplorer%20%28Mac%29%202.2.1.6), that lets you access and/or mount the device as if it were an external hard drive. Then, you had better be most careful, as you can likely kill some apps if you delete the wrong files.

Comment: You're wrong. All apps are sandboxed to ~/Applications. They get their own folder (a long, random string of I believe 16 characters) and can do things from there. No part of an app installed from the App Store will ever have a single file outside of that folder. Even their Library and Documents and other folders are restricted to their parent app folder. But you are right in that deleting an app will delete all this data (aside from anything that is stored in iCloud Documents). Also it's of note that as of iOS 6+, you cannot modify files, not even in your user account. It is all read-only.

Comment: @cksum. There is an app folder called /Apps and another called /Media/ These appear at the top level of my iOS Phone Folder structure. Is this what you mean?

Comment: ~/Applications is where third party apps are installed to. Each is installed into their own folder (e.g., 75E6636C-F122-480A-F5E7-1127DF17D221) and only get access to that. They cannot modify, touch, or produce files outside of their respective parent folders. All they can do is hook into approved APIs. If they use anything that isn't kosher, Apple won't let them into the store. When you delete an app from your system (tap and hold on your home screen), it deletes that parent folder (so 75E6636C-F122-480A-F5E7-1127DF17D221) and any local content with it).

Comment: Media is reserved for default apps and their files. Things like music, books, photos, etc. are stored here. It is essentially all users content. iOS has two important users: root and mobile. Root is the system (obviously). Mobile is you. Unlike OS X, which can have multiple users, iOS gives you one. When you wipe your phone, it simply removes the content in /private/var/mobile. But that's actually not the top level. The top level is / (obviously). You just can't see that because you are probably not jailbroken. Default apps are installed to /Applications, that's top level.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [iClean](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iclean-remove-clean-all-deleted/id661800424?mt=8) - it forces the OS to empty all cached and temp files.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how exactly this works, with pictures or an explanation?

Comment: I can't see iClean working as advertised. I wouldn't be surprised if it gets pulled from the store. Apps can't alter anything outside of their respective parent folders. They are sandboxed and only allowed to talk to the OS through strict APIs. If an app uses an undocumented API (hack), they get rejected from the approval process. iClean claim it can clear out chaches and lingering content, but I can't see that. It would need access to the /mobile/Library directory and it would never get that.

Comment: @cksum You are correct when you say apps operate in their own sandbox, but apps definitely CAN cause the OS to make changes to other applications.  Each application has a Caches and Temp folder, which is not only accessible to the app, but is directly managed by the OS.  When the OS notices that the devices storage is too low, it automatically clears all data out of all the temp and cache directories of all apps.  What iClean does, is simply create a large file that fills up the device, which causes the OS to delete all cached files, and then iClean deletes the file it created.

Comment: Many apps use these cache folders incorrectly, not understanding that the os can delete them at any time - so its possible you may lose some important files - just a heads up.

Comment: What good would causing iOS to jettison your apps cache file do? The app advertises the removal of cruft from the OS and other software. Clearly it can't do that. So it fills up its temp folder and iOS dumps it. Big deal. Smells like even more of a scam to me. Install app. It balloons an empty tmp file. Said file is then cleared out. App reports you've just saved X GB! Congrats. iOS doesn't empty it's mobile user cache so who cares if it empties the cache of iClean?

Comment: And actually if you read the description of iClean you'd see that that's exactly what it says it does. It's supposed to overwrite deleted files so you cannot recover them anymore. I assume it does this just as you say. But that's not at all what the OP is asking about. As I said, no official app in the App Store can clean anything from your device that you cannot do yourself.

Comment: Clearly it does do that - read what I wrote again - it causes the OS to release EVERY app's cache and temp files. And yes you can easily replicate its functionality, its not rocket science.

Comment: Check the checker app too.It also claims to do the same.Is it possible now?